# Which Eclipse version should I download?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

I am on a Windows machine.
Want to practise Java for the web using: [Tomcat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat), Java, [JSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages)'s, [Spring Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework), and [Hibernate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibernate_%28Java%29).

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

(Silly question, but I am a newbie and don't want to get the wrong IDE version.)

Comment: Funny how all four answers to date suggest Netbeans. Are the Sun/Oracle astroturfers out in force today? :-)

Comment: Netbeans users are merely vocal and Europe's only just waking up.

Answer (score 6):

You want to practise java for the web using: tomcat, java, jsp's, spring framework, etc.
then you should download the [Enterprised version.](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/galileo/SR1/eclipse-jee-galileo-SR1-win32.zip)

Personally I would prefer [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/). I use it frequently and I find it better(simpler rather) than Eclipse.

Comment: +1 for recommending NetBeans.

Comment: I prefer Eclipse for everything except Swing GUI design.

Comment: What does netbeans have that eclipse doesn't?

Comment: @fastcodejava: Read this: http://javabyexample.wisdomplug.com/component/content/article/61-select-your-ide-netbeans-vs-eclipse.html

Comment: @fastcodejava: Intuitiveness.

Comment: @Vinegar: you should listen to Jon Skeet's talk on the London DevDays. He has some interesting things to say about so called "intuitiveness".

Comment: Eclipse and Netbeans are both free, but why go with netbeans when the marketshare is with Eclipse?  Some Java shops go with IntelliJ, but that commercial product is not need for your learning purposes. Again, if you are going for a marketable skill, thus an IDE on your resume, then is it better to know Spanish or Portuguese in the U.S. ?

Answer (score 5):

Who says you need Eclipse?  NetBeans and IntelliJ are both good choices as well.

If you're a newbie to Java, I'd recommend staying away from Tomcat and JSP until you can write the core language comfortably.  Likewise, stay away from Hibernate until you've mastered JDBC.  Spring is very complex tool that should come last in your development.

My recommended order would be:

1. Base Java, including JDBC.
2. Tomcat, servlets, and JSPs using JSTL (allowing CRUD-based web apps)
3. Spring

UPDATE: It's great that you're already familiar with relational databases, ORM, objects, and DI.  But I'd still recommend that you learn the language basics first.  If you're really good at C#, it won't take you too long.  There's an idiom to every language that you'll want to know to write well.  Take the time to try and find it.

Comment: Cent percent agreement with duffymo here. As a compliment you might want to look at this somehow related thread, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402056/should-i-do-more-javase-before-jumping-to-javaee/402088#402088

Comment: i'm coming for .net, so I know nhibernate already, and MVC framework and DI.

Comment: +1 for LEARN THE LANGUAGE FIRST!

Comment: intellij is a commercial iDE though? :)

Comment: Yes, that's true of the full-featured version, but there's a community edition now that's worthwhile.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend either the classic or IDE for java developers first, and then as you get familiar install the other plugins that you'd want/need.  That way you'll learn the structure better.  That being said, use Netbeans instead.

Answer (score 3):

You should go for [Eclipse Java EE](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/galileo/SR1/eclipse-jee-galileo-SR1-linux-gtk.tar.gz) but AFAIK it won't come with app servers bundled in. So you'll need to install those in addition to Eclipse and configure it.

However, you can go with Netbeans and it all comes pre bundled and pre configured and you can simply get started with writing code.

Comment: Disclaimer: Not trying to start a Eclipse v/s NetBeans debate. NetBeans as of now is just simpler to get started IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

As a learner Eclipse would be a better.
You can follow this URL to download it:
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/galileo/SR1/eclipse-java-galileo-SR1-win32.zip.

Once you are comfortable with the basic functionality with Java, you can start with any 
web Server or an application server.
Then you can implement the Framework.

Personally Eclipse is very friendly in use.

Answer (score 0):

Don't go for any of these.

As you are working on windows platform I would suggest you to first try out [JBuilder](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/jbuilder). Checkit out! It is better in all ways compared to Eclipse and Net Beans but to gather, because it gives a Visual way to build your GUIs!

Comment: Bad suggestion for someone learning Java. JBuilder is not free (costs a hell of a lot of money, actually!). There are plugins (both free and commercial) for Eclipse that provide GUI building abilities, and Netbeans comes with this built-in.

Comment: Agreed some tools may provide GUI building abilities but they cannot convert Eclipse to a true RAD tool like JBuilder. In spite of being commercial JBuilder is well worth its price. I would like to clear the fact that I don't use JBuilder but we have a developer who works in JBuilder in our company.

You know it is so easy with JBuilder. Place a widget, set required properties and select the event to which you want to react and code in that event.

As easy as 123!

Answer (score 0):

I am a long time IntelliJ IDEA fan, but if I need to do AspectJ work, I turn to [STS](http://www.springsource.com/products/sts). I found it real easy to get started with Eclipse because it seems to contain the plugins I need already.